# Magento displaying FormKey when click on Add To Cart button

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart, addtocart

In magento 1.8.1.0, when I click on Add to Cart url show FormKey.
It does not redirect to checkout cart page.

Following is my addtocart.phtml file button code.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Following is CartController.php

```
protected function _getCart()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
}    

public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        /**
         * Check product availability
         */
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

I tried to search but did not get proper solution.
[Click here](http://www.geniusmods.com/) for site where I get error.

Comment: Could you provide the url returned by `getAddToCartUrl` method?

Comment: @DenisSpalenza http://www.geniusmods.com/ this is site url

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: i tried this but not work same problem